pyserial не выводит весь список COM портов
вот все ком порты которые у меня есть
в ответ на свою програму serial.tools.list_ports.comports() я получаю лишь COM1 - Communications Port (COM1). Когда в коде я прописываю serial.tools.list_ports.main()
то выводит все ком порты правда без названия, только номер. Вопрос как это решить? На другом модеме всё ок а вот прикупил новый модем начал допиливать прогу для него и тут такое, модем если что на чипе от MediaTek и дрова тоже MTKашеные. Вот весь код для понимания ситуации
import serial
import re
import time
import serial.tools.list_ports

def serialget():
    ncm=1

    while True:
            ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
            for port in ports:
                    for i in port.__str__().split('\n'):
                        try:
                            ii=""
                            if i.find('Intel Mobile (acm2)') != -1:
                                ncm=0
                                ii=i
                                print("fine")
                            elif i.find('USB Serial Device') != -1:
                                ncm=11
                                ii=i
                            elif i.find('MD AT') != -1:
                                print("FM350")
                                ncm = 350
                                ii=i
                            com = re.findall(r'\w{1,100}', ii)
                            for el in com[:1]:
                                comport = str(el)
                            ser = serial.Serial(port=comport, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0, xonxoff=False, rtscts=True, writeTimeout=None, dsrdtr=False, interCharTimeout=None)
                            return ser, ncm


                        except:
                            time.sleep(2)
                            serialget()

serialget()


Вообщем я нашёл способ решить свою проблему это просто в цикле не конвертировать ports в str, а написать там description
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports=serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for a in ports:
    print(a.description)

в консоли мне уже выводит весь список портов так что то кто так же как и я затупил пользуйтесь
